# Getting an error by making VBox full screen on Windows?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

Despite installation of the package, getting same error again.

```
Error : kernel module failed
Kernel headers not found for target kernel4.19.0-8-amd64. Please install them and execute
```

Host: Win 10

VBox: Debian 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical issue, actually not an issue simply missing headers. Run following
commands

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-4.19.0-8-amd64 
$ sudo apt install dkms
```

Then run guest script again

```
sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Finally reboot the machine

```
$ sudo reboot
```